# cython c++ undefined reference to std::ios_base::failure

Tags: c++, python, cython

I just wrote cython code just as simple as that

```
# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.map cimport map,pair
from ios import *



cdef map[int,int] * u = new map[int,int]()

cdef add_item(int n, int x):
    cdef pair[int,int]p = pair[int,int](n,x)
    u.insert(p)

def add(int n, int x):
    add_item(n,x)
```

added build file like

```
def make_ext(modname, pyxfilename):
    from distutils.extension import Extension
    return Extension(name=modname,
                     sources=[pyxfilename],
                     language='C++')
```

and run simple script like

```
import hello
```

with lines

import pyximport
pyximport.install()

in my sitecustomize.py

At script execution i get `ImportError: Building module hello failed: ['ImportError: /home/odomontois/.pyxbld/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/hello.so: undefined symbol: _ZTINSt8ios_base7failureE\n']`

`c++filt  _ZTINSt8ios_base7failureE` prints `typeinfo for std::ios_base::failure`

Is there any possibility to find out what object file i should include and how to do this in  my pyxbld file for example.

Comment: Got the exact same error message, but your answer does now work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by adding

```
libraries=["stdc++"]
```

to pyxbld